# My site has been tagged as Malware by Chrome! What now?

Tags: javascript, malware, malware-detection

I'm completing the development of a site I didn't build (I designed it, but another has built it so far) and recently when I visit the site in Chrome I get a "Malware Detected!" Warning box.

The site is `http://kenbrook.org/` It's for a summer camp, and it's a basic brochure type site with your average marketing content. It was built on the ModX content management framework, and uses a few plugins.

I have no clue how or what this is from, or how to deal with it. In troubleshooting another isssue with this site (CSS related) a user in another stackoverflow question mentioned an insight about that malware problem: [When using the firefox webdeveloper toolbar to edit CSS, why do some image disappear when the toolbar is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325478/when-using-the-firefox-webdeveloper-toolbar-to-edit-css-why-do-some-image-disapp/3373080#3373080)

I'm not even sure what that script is on the site for?! Can anyone give me any insight about this issue and how I should begin to resolve it? I'm responsible for it now, so "Go back to the original developer and get him to work it out" is not an option.

In case you'd rather not visit the site, here's the warning text that Chrome is giving me:

> Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!
>   The website at kenbrook.org contains elements from the site www.spiritek.co.jp, which appears to host malware – software that can hurt your computer or otherwise operate without your consent. Just visiting a site that contains malware can infect your computer.
>   For detailed information about the problems with these elements, visit the Google Safe Browsing diagnostic page for www.spiritek.co.jp.
>   Learn more about how to protect yourself from harmful software online.
>    I understand that visiting this site may harm my computer.

Comment: I don't see this on  Google Chrome 5.0.375.125 on Windows

Comment: I'm getting it from Chrome on MAC and on Ubutnu.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with Chrome 6.0.462.14 Dev on Windows; however, a valid question like this would probably fit better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do see it on Chrome for Windows.

Comment: I get the error on Chrome 6.0.472.14 dev.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Nathan Taylor. Didn't know about that site.

Comment: @Jag2007 No sweat. It's brand new. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the script at the very bottom of /assets/js/slides.js is doing, but I'd try taking the last 5 lines out and see if the cross fade thing still works. I seriously doubt that the "Browser Slide-Show script" has the need to obfuscate the JavaScript at the bottom. Someone wrote to this file.

If you have software that's able to write to slides.js, you have bigger problems. Get the security on the web server tightened up (apply latest updates, patches, check permissions, change passwords, etc).

Comment: this is it... that code at the bottom is an obfuscator that links to www.spiritek.co.jp. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xa4ku/1/

Comment: Yup - that worked. Dunno how it got there though....

Comment: Not knowing how it got there should scare you hopefully! Follow the second half of my answer to help protect yourself from it happening again. Google also has a process for removing the warning: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=163633

Comment: @Jag2007 If that got there without you're knowing chances are you have a vulnerability in your website that someone is exploiting. It could be a few things but mostly likely it's a [SQL Injection Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or unvalidated form input that displays data on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're obviously linking something from that japanese site (image, flash, ad iframe, applet), and that japanese site is the one that is tagged for malware, not your site. Just remove the link to whatever it is and you'll be fine.

Comment: Trouble is I don't know what on earth would be linking to that site. Nothing I've intentionally linked to.

Answer (score -1):

The only javascript I see loading is some google stuff.  There's no reference to spiritek.co.jp.  One guess is that

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-4573442-6']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

is an account number for www.spiritek.co.jp.

If you take out the javascript, does your problem go away?

Comment: That all refers to my Google Analytics account.